# Feeding command line from the bash script

Tags: bash

Is there a way to create a bash script that when run would feed the command line with some text (command to execute) and place the cursor at the end?

So it should not execute the command, it would only happen if I press [Enter] key. I just want to be able to sometimes change some of the parameters that are in the command.

Example:

```
    # ./do_command.sh
    # some__very_long_command_with_plenty_of_params param1 param2 param3 | <- and the cursor 
is here waiting for me to just approve hitting the [Enter] or possibly tweak the params before doing so
```

What I have so far is just the script echo'ing the command, which requires me to copy-paste it.

Comment: Why not instead work on modifying `./do_command.sh` so that you *don't* need to modify/tweak the parameters? That way you can just put the long command into the script and have it execute automatically.

Comment: Because I need to run the command very often with some of the parameters just slightly changed sometimes. I want to be able to inspect (and possibly change) the default parameters and simply approve (pressing [Enter]) if these are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can achieve this exactly using only Bash. Some additional features from your terminal application might be needed.

The options I can think of:

- write a Bash function with optional parameters for each very long command with plenty of params. The function can also print the command and ask for confirmation ;

For instance:

```
myfunc() {
   param1=${1:default1}
   param2=${1:default2}
   cmd="command --param $para1 --param $param2"
   echo running $cmd
   read -p "<ENTER> to run, <CTRL-C> to abort"
   $cmd
}
```

- use a text completion tool such as [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash), [TextExpander](https://textexpander.com) that will prompt your for the arguments when you write a specific sequence of characters and write the result when you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
- use Bash aliases with online expansion: create an alias for each of the very long command with plenty of params, and then type the alias, but do not press enter (yet), press <kbd>CTRL-ALT-E</kbd> ; the line will expand and you will be able to review, modify, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

For instance:

```
$ aliase myfunc="command --param 1 --param 2"
$ myfunc <CTRL-ALT-E>
$ command --param 1 --param 2
```

- use 'permanent history with hashtags': run the command with the very long command with plenty of params once, but terminate with a comment to give that line a 'name'. Then, you can use <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> to search the name ('hashtag')

For instance:

```
$ command --param 1 --param 2 # myfunc
```

Then type <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> <kbd>my</kbd>

```
(reverse-i-search)`my': command --param 1 --param 2 # myfunc
```

to retrieve the command.

Comment: Thanks, alias and then ctrl+alt+e does exactly what I was looking for. It makes me move the command from the dedicated script to .bashrc but that is even better in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`do_command` is really just a wrapper around the `read` command.

```
cmd="some__very_long_command_with_plenty_of_params"
args=("foo bar" "param2" "param3")
read -e -i "$(printf '%q' "$cmd"; printf ' %q' "${args[@]}")" cmd
eval "$cmd"
```

Generally, `eval` should not be used, but here, you are specifically trying to execute an arbitrary command, which is what `eval` is designed to do. This is no more dangerous than typing your command directly at the `bash` prompt.

The `-e` command tells `read` to use the Readline library to edit the command line (just like the regular prompt). `-e` provides a default value. The `printf` commands ensure that the command name and the default arguments are printed in a way that can be reused with the `eval` command. Be aware that `%q` doesn't use quotes; it uses a backslash to escape only those characters that *must* be escaped, so the argument `foo bar` is displayed as `foo\ bar`, not `"foo bar"` or `'foo bar'`.